journalctl not persistent AND 'Clock change detected. Flushing caches', 'Time jumped backwards, rotating'
System details:
WSL2: Ubuntu 24.04.1
Win11: 23H2 build 22631.4037
WSL version: 2.2.4.0
Kernel: 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2

In 'journalctl' ('dmesg') and 'syslog' I see a lot of 'Clock change detected. Flushing caches.' and 'Time jumped backwards, rotating.' messages.
See Edit2 below.
This looks to have started shortly (nearly directly) after upgrading WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04.5 to Ubuntu 24.04.1.
I did the upgrade on 2024-09-12 and got the "System upgrade is complete." message at 17:40.
I suspect this is causing journalctl not to log persistent.
Even with /var/log/journal/ to be present and 'Storage=persistent' to be configured in '/etc/systemd/journald.conf'.
Old journalctl messages look to be lost, even after a few hours.
What could be the issue?
The at 13:00 the oldest message showing up are from just over an hour ago:
$ journalctl 
Sep 15 11:35:31 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-resolved[292]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
Sep 15 11:35:31 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-journald[50]: Time jumped backwards, rotating.

While the system is up for more than 15 hours:
$ uptime
 13:00:46 up 15:35,  2 users,  load average: 0.10, 0.05, 0.01

So far I have seen the log to start with 'Clock change detected. Flushing caches.'
I tried to correct this by deleting the content of '/var/log/journal/' with:
systemctl status systemd-journald
sudo systemctl stop systemd-journald-dev-log.socket
sudo systemctl stop  systemd-journald.socket
sudo systemctl stop systemd-journald
sudo rm /var/log/journal/* -rf
sudo systemctl start systemd-journald

but no change.
First time seen in '/var/log/syslog'
2024-09-12T18:13:41.079123+02:00 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-resolved[269]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
2024-09-12T18:13:41.079123+02:00 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-resolved[269]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
2024-09-12T18:14:12.855185+02:00 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-resolved[269]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
2024-09-12T18:14:44.510248+02:00 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-resolved[269]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
2024-09-12T18:15:16.254113+02:00 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-resolved[269]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
2024-09-12T18:15:47.900499+02:00 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-resolved[269]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
2024-09-12T18:16:19.571240+02:00 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-resolved[269]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
2024-09-12T18:16:51.214299+02:00 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-resolved[269]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
2024-09-12T18:17:22.709058+02:00 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-resolved[269]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
2024-09-12T18:17:54.230828+02:00 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-resolved[269]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
2024-09-12T18:18:25.739595+02:00 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-resolved[269]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.

<snip>

2024-09-12T18:26:18.238966+02:00 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-resolved[269]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
2024-09-12T18:26:18.240566+02:00 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 kernel: systemd-journald[50]: Time jumped backwards, rotating.

Not sure if time synchronisation is involved.
NTP:
$ timedatectl
               Local time: Sun 2024-09-15 14:10:00 CEST
           Universal time: Sun 2024-09-15 12:10:00 UTC
                 RTC time: Sun 2024-09-15 12:10:01
                Time zone: Europe/Amsterdam (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no

$ timedatectl timesync-status
       Server: 185.125.190.57 (ntp.ubuntu.com)
Poll interval: 32s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s)
         Leap: normal
      Version: 4
      Stratum: 2
    Reference: B7A08584
    Precision: 1us (-25)
Root distance: 815us (max: 5s)
       Offset: -2.699961s
        Delay: 19.915ms
       Jitter: 22.693ms
 Packet count: 1885
    Frequency: -43.497ppm

Edit1 (2024-09-21):
I created a backup of Ubuntu 24.04.1 and restored my Ubuntu 22.04.5 backup.
With Ubuntu 22.04.5 'journalctl' logging works fine again:
$ journalctl -t systemd-resolved
Sep 10 21:12:04 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-resolved[210]: Positive Trust Anchors:
Sep 10 21:12:04 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-resolved[210]: . IN DS 20326 8 2 e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d
Sep 10 21:12:04 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-resolved[210]: Negative trust anchors: home.arpa 10.in-addr.arpa 16.172.in-addr.arpa 17.172.in-addr.arpa 18.172.in-addr.arpa 19.172.in-a>
Sep 10 21:12:04 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-resolved[210]: Using system hostname 'DESKTOP-E6DGEM9'.
-- Boot 6c5874aebd5d4e689223fd8c16b621db --
Sep 20 20:32:24 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-resolved[226]: Positive Trust Anchors:
Sep 20 20:32:24 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-resolved[226]: . IN DS 20326 8 2 e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d
Sep 20 20:32:24 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-resolved[226]: Negative trust anchors: home.arpa 10.in-addr.arpa 16.172.in-addr.arpa 17.172.in-addr.arpa 18.172.in-addr.arpa 19.172.in-a>
Sep 20 20:32:24 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-resolved[226]: Using system hostname 'DESKTOP-E6DGEM9'.

$ journalctl -t systemd-journald
Sep 10 21:12:02 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-journald[46]: Journal started
Sep 10 21:12:02 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-journald[46]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/b745815e4a31140e822ee92b63e6aa28) is 8.0M, max 388.4M, 380.4M free.
Sep 10 21:12:02 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-journald[46]: Time spent on flushing to /var/log/journal/b745815e4a31140e822ee92b63e6aa28 is 8.963ms for 438 entries.
Sep 10 21:12:02 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-journald[46]: System Journal (/var/log/journal/b745815e4a31140e822ee92b63e6aa28) is 4.0G, max 4.0G, 0B free.
-- Boot 6c5874aebd5d4e689223fd8c16b621db --
Sep 20 20:32:23 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-journald[46]: Journal started
Sep 20 20:32:23 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-journald[46]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/b745815e4a31140e822ee92b63e6aa28) is 8.0M, max 388.4M, 380.4M free.
Sep 20 20:32:23 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-journald[46]: Time spent on flushing to /var/log/journal/b745815e4a31140e822ee92b63e6aa28 is 129.966ms for 438 entries.
Sep 20 20:32:23 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd-journald[46]: System Journal (/var/log/journal/b745815e4a31140e822ee92b63e6aa28) is 3.3G, max 4.0G, 659.8M free.

And oldest messages are from April:
$ sudo journalctl 
Apr 30 21:09:01 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 CRON[1789623]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Apr 30 21:09:01 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 CRON[1789624]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Apr 30 21:09:01 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 CRON[1789623]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root

Maybe I should look into a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04.1 for next try...
/Edit1
Edit2 (2024-09-21)
Comparing with Ubuntu 22.04.5. I noticed the following:
$ timedatectl
               Local time: Sat 2024-09-21 11:29:36 CEST
           Universal time: Sat 2024-09-21 09:29:36 UTC
                 RTC time: Sat 2024-09-21 09:29:36
                Time zone: Europe/Amsterdam (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no

So with 22.04.5 NTP service is 'inactive'.
systemd-timesyncd.service should not start because of: "ConditionVirtualization=!container was not met"
$ systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service
○ systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
  Condition: start condition failed at Sat 2024-09-21 11:30:29 CEST; 29min ago
             └─ ConditionVirtualization=!container was not met
       Docs: man:(8)

Sep 20 20:32:24 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Network Time Synchronization being skipped.
Sep 21 11:30:29 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Network Time Synchronization being skipped.

So with Ubuntu 22.04.5 'systemd-timesyncd.service' is not started.
But with 24.04.1 I had the following:
10:51:04    Sep 17 00:58:32 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd[1]: Starting systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization...
<snip>
10:51:04    Sep 17 00:58:32 DESKTOP-E6DGEM9 systemd[1]: Started systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization.

This should be before I made any changes to config related to timing.
If someone has the same issue can you verify with systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service if Network Time Synchronization is active?
/Edit2

I upgraded again to Ubuntu 24.04.1 and solved it with the following steps:
systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service
sudo systemctl stop systemd-timesyncd.service
# inactive (dead) since Sun 2024-09-29 20:26:55 CEST
sudo systemctl disable systemd-timesyncd.service

After stopping the service the messages Clock change detected. Flushing caches. indeed stopped.
To prevent the timesyncd service to start I disabled it also.
journalctl -S "2024-09-29 20:00" -t systemd-resolved
# last message at: Sep 29 20:26:32

